# libphonenumber-for-PHP fails to validate phone number

Tags: php, validation, libphonenumber

Iam using https://github.com/davideme/libphonenumber-for-PHP for international phone no validation.It's working fine,but as per the guidence in that github page i have given

**"$swissNumberStr = "044 668 18 00";"** and **$phoneUtil->parse($swissNumberStr, "CH")**;

as inputs...
and when we are calling

**$isValid = $phoneUtil->isValidNumber($swissNumberProto);**

it should return true..because its a valid one.But for me it's getting false..any help would be much appreciated..

**demo.php**

```
use com\google\i18n\phonenumbers\PhoneNumberUtil;
use com\google\i18n\phonenumbers\PhoneNumberFormat;
use com\google\i18n\phonenumbers\NumberParseException;

require_once 'PhoneNumberUtil.php';

$swissNumberStr = "044 668 18 00";
$phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();
try {
    $swissNumberProto = $phoneUtil->parseAndKeepRawInput($swissNumberStr, "CH");
    echo $phoneUtil->getNumberType($swissNumberProto);
    //var_dump($swissNumberProto);
} catch (NumberParseException $e) {
    echo $e;
}
$isValid = $phoneUtil->isValidNumber($swissNumberProto);//return true
var_dump($isValid);
// Produces "+41446681800"
echo $phoneUtil->format($swissNumberProto, PhoneNumberFormat::INTERNATIONAL) . PHP_EOL;
echo $phoneUtil->format($swissNumberProto, PhoneNumberFormat::NATIONAL) . PHP_EOL;
echo $phoneUtil->format($swissNumberProto, PhoneNumberFormat::E164) . PHP_EOL;

echo $phoneUtil->formatOutOfCountryCallingNumber($swissNumberProto, "US") . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Might help to see your real code...

Comment: Remove the prefixed 0

Comment: @fayyazkl it..remains same..other lines are giving exact output.but validation line only shows false..

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong function for parsing.

Use

`phUtil.Parse(germanNumberStr, "CH")`

instead of parseAndKeepRawInput